# Principle of duality

Tags: boolean-expression

The following is given in my textbook-

> When we start with a boolean relation, another boolean relation can be derived by:
>
> - changing **OR** to **AND**
> - changing **AND** to **OR**
> - replacing **0** to **1** and **1** to **0**
>
> This derived expression is known as the ***dual*** of the initial expression.

So dual of  1 AND 0 is 0 OR 1. Isn't?

What about the dual of **X OR X'** ? Is it **X' AND X**?  (Note that ***'*** stands for complement.)

PS -

> One change we did not need to make as part of this interchange was to
> complement. We say that complement is a self-dual operation. The
> identity or do-nothing operation x (copy the input to the output) is
> also self-dual.

What does the above line mean?

Source : [Duality principle in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Duality_principle)

Comment: Sometimes textbooks have bounties for errors; you may be able to get some cash.  I think that changing OR to NOR, AND to NAND, and X to NOT X might be the ticket.

Comment: @mevets Please read PS.

Comment: I will try; but my earlier comment, I was thinking duality <=> rewriting boolean expressions; which is used to normalize before other systems...  But I think the notion is that the inverse of negation is negation.  So negation : 1 -> 0, 0 -> 1.  The inverse of negation: 0 -> 1, 1 -> 0.  Thus the inverse of negation is itself negation.   Similarly copy :  0 -> 0, 1 -> 1.  The inverse of copy: 0 -> 1, 1 -> 1.  So the inverse of copy is copy.

Comment: @mevets I have noticed that they change 1 with 0 and 0 with 1 . But why don't they change X with X' and vice versa?